# "constant expression not representable in type Integer"

Tags: vb.net

Please see the following webpage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx#64mig_topic6.  It states:

"
These considerations led the Windows team to select an abstract data model called LLP64 (or P64). In the LLP64 data model, only pointers expand to 64 bits; all other basic data types (integer and long) remain 32 bits in length.
"
I thought a Long was 64 bit? For example, please see the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim l As Long
        l = 1234355667778444444
        Dim o As Integer
        o = 1234355667778444444
    End Sub
```

Initialising l is successful.  However, initialising o produces an error: "constant expression not representable in type Integer".

Why does the document state that "all other basic data types (integer and long) remain 32 bits in length"?  In my example above the variable: l is a 64 bit data type.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is 32 bits in VB.NET. Your constant exceeds that size.

Comment: Thanks but I know that.  This does not answer my question.

Comment: What is your question then? You're trying to initialize `o`, an Integer with a value larger than 32 bits.

Comment: From the question: "Why does the document state that "all other basic data types (integer and long) remain 32 bits in length"? In my example above the variable: l is a 64 bit data type.".

Comment: Ah sorry I had things mixed up. I only briefly scanned the linked article. But perhaps they're referring to `long`, the C data type, to which their quote does apply.

Comment: Indeed, I think they are referring to the native C types, but were just a little lax in how they referred to them. The .NET data types are always the same size (with the exception of IntPtr).

Comment: Thanks. How is a 64 bit data type represented in a 32 bit process? I.e. If you choose x86 as the target processor.

Comment: In memory it's just 8 bytes instead of 4. On the CPU, two registers are used to represent the whole 64 bit value. 64 bit arithmetic happens in two steps.